# Angular JS scope variable not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Learning to use angularJS,

I have this particular code in my index.html. Dynamic typing works in the upper part, but the injection doesn't. What possibly might have been gone wrong?

**Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test1</title>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="">
<!-- Dynamic Type -->

      <input type="text" ng-model="name1" /><br>
      <h1>Hello {{name1}}</h1>

<!-- End dynamic Type -->

 <!-- Scope Injection begin-->
      <div class="container" ng-controller="myController">
         <input type="text" ng-model="naam" /><br>
         <h3>Looping</h3>
         <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customerlist | filter:naam | orderBy:'city'"> {{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city}} </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function myController ($scope) {

             $scope.customerlist = [
             {name: 'Raj Bannerjee', city: 'Zaire'},
             {name: 'Prasun Bannerjee', city: 'Udaipur'},
             {name: 'Raj Malhotra', city: 'Dubai'},
             {name: 'Prasun Joshi', city: 'Mumbai'}
             ];

         }

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you see it not working? Here is a jsfiddle with it (slightly modified) that works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/b69p4zj9/

Comment: Maybe I see it. Are you asking about how the filter works?

Comment: you need to tell angular that myController is a controller `angular.controller('myController', function($scope) {....`

Comment: What version of angular you use?

Comment: @deitch no I had been following an ebook, where it was simply working with the code. But when I tried, it didn't. Learning has to be from scratch, that's why :D Thanks for the modification :) will have to do some more reading it seems

Comment: @IlanFrumer I'm using the 1.3x version (latest)

Comment: Oh, yeah, 1.3 would do it.

Comment: @LearnerAlways look at your console, you'll probably see this error: `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 1.3 angular disabled using global controller constructors:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018

> With the exception of simple demos, it is not helpful to use globals
>   for controller constructors. This adds a new method to
>   `$controllerProvider` to re-enable the old behavior, but disables this
>   feature by default.
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: `$controller` will no longer look for controllers on
>   `window`. The old behavior of looking on `window` for controllers was
>   originally intended for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found
>   that allowing global controller functions encouraged poor practices,
>   so we resolved to disable this behavior by default.

So you must refactor it like so:

```
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customerlist = [
    {name: 'Raj Bannerjee', city: 'Zaire'},
    {name: 'Prasun Bannerjee', city: 'Udaipur'},
    {name: 'Raj Malhotra', city: 'Dubai'},
    {name: 'Prasun Joshi', city: 'Mumbai'}
  ];
}]);
```

And also refer to your module:

```
<body ng-app="app">
```